# MultiPageEditorPart with editors side by side

Tags: eclipse, parallel-processing, editor, rcp

I have a rcp project with a custom MultiPageEditorPart which contains two editor pages. I would want to be able to show them side by side, is there a way to do this? I couldn't find a solution over the Internet.

I tried Window -> New Window or Window -> Editor -> Clone and I get a file opened with my MultiPageEditorPart twice side by side but the problem is if I switch in one place to a page editor it automatically switches to the same page editor in the other.

What I want is to have both pages of the MultiPageEditorPart in parallel so I can edit in one and see some changes in the other.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `MultiPageEditorPart` does not support this.

It uses a single `CTabFolder` to contain all the pages, this doesn't support showing multiple tabs at once.

Depending on what your pages are like you might be able to use a `FormEditor` with multiple sections on a single page (like several pages on the MANIFEST.MF / plugin.xml editor).