# e3/e4 compat app: Drag and drop part programmatically

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a compatibility app (based on Neon) with two (`EditorPart`-based) editors next to each other, in tabs. Both work on the same input, and the second one is opened programmatically from the first one (works using the respective match flags).

I can drag and drop the editor parts per mouse into a new position, no problem.

**Now I'd like to do that programmatically, so that the editors are displayed next to each other rather than in tabs. How can I do that?**

*Notes*: I've had a look at some of the split editor area hacks, but I don't think they are available anymore because the internal classes have changed (and I'd rather not go there anyway). I also cannot access e4 services via DI as I'm in `plugin.xml` provisioned editors. I can access some services (e.g., EventBroker) via OSGi, but am having trouble getting, e.g., a valid part service.

Comment: Why not use `MultiPageEditorPart` (or `FormEditor`) to use a single editor with multiple pages?

Comment: Thanks @greg-449! As per [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221576/731040), `MultiPageEditorPart` doesn't support side-by-side display. Other than that it's a good idea to put both parts into one parent, guess it also eases communication between the two. I think that `FormEditor` isn't an option for me, as one of the editor is a GEF5 `AbstractFXEditor`, but will check.